# Spark with own map and reduce functions python

Tags: python, mapreduce, apache-spark

I'm trying to do a mapreduce like operation using python spark. Here is what i have and my problem.

```
object_list = list(objects) #this is precomputed earlier in my script
def my_map(obj):
    return [f(obj)]
def my_reduce(obj_list1, obj_list2):
    return obj_list1 + obj_list2
```

What I am trying to do in is something like the following:

```
myrdd = rdd(object_list) #objects are now spread out
myrdd.map(my_map)
myrdd.reduce(my_reduce)
my_result = myrdd.result()
```

where `my_result` should now just be = `[f(obj1), f(obj2), ..., f(objn)]`. I want to use spark purely for the speed, my script has been taking to long when doing this in a forloop. Does anyone know how to do the above in spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would usually look like this:

```
myrdd = sc.parallelize(object_list)
my_result = myrdd.map(f).reduce(lambda a,b:a+b)
```

There is a `sum` function for RDDs, so this could also be:

```
myrdd = sc.parallelize(object_list)
my_result = myrdd.map(f).sum()
```

However, this will give you a single number.  `f(obj1)+f(obj2)+...`

If you want an array of all the responses `[f(obj1),f(obj2), ...]`, you would not use `.reduce()` or `.sum()` but instead use `.collect()`:

```
myrdd = sc.parallelize(object_list)
my_result = myrdd.map(f).collect()
```